# "defined by" or "defined as"?

Tags: prepositions

MY main interest is in the mathematical context, where one defines objects by a formula. I can imagine 2 cases :

1. Direct case, "direct definition": *The function f is defined by/as f=a+b+c*
2. Implicit definition: *The number x is defined by/as a = g(x)*

I would tend to use as for the case 1 and by for the second one.

Comment: If pressed, I'd use _by_ in the second case (the function has to be 1 to 1 for x to be defined, of course) - but why not then write x = g [index -1] (a) ? (Sorry, I can't use the normal superscript characters to show the inverse function.) I'd use _thus_ (or a colon followed on the next line by the formula) in the first case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth x = g⁻¹(a) -- Unicode has a large number of characters available via charmap in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

I would agree with the use of "by" in both your examples, but if I were writing something like the following examples I would use "as":

> The value of *x* is defined as equal to the sum *a + b*
>   In this example, *x* is defined as equivalent to ...

So:

> ... defined *by* [a formula]
>   ... defined *as* [a value]

Answer (score 0):

For the case 1, I think 'by' is more correct because 'by ...' is an abbreviation for 'by the formula ...'.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, both *by* and *as* are acceptable in either of the examples given.  But as mathematical statements, both examples have problems.

In the first example, “The function *f* is defined by/as *f=a+b+c*”, unless *a, b, c* all are previously-defined functions or constants, the arguments of *f* and its dependence on them is unclear, *ie* undefined, hence the statement that “*f* is defined” is improper.  Instead say (for example) “Let *f(x) = a+b+c(x)*” [in the case where *a, b* are constants and *c(x)* is a function].

In the second example, *as* is likely to be unacceptable to many mathematicians, and *by*, while acceptable, misleading. That is, the expression  “*x* is defined as *a = g(x)*”  would be viewed as nonsense, and  “*x* is defined by *a = g(x)*”  as an assertion that needs to be proved, rather than as a definition, because g⁻¹(a) might be undefined or might have multiple values.   Instead say “Let *x* be such that *a = g(x)*.  To see that x is [well-defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined), consider ...”